# $u_t = u_{xx} + H_1(x)e^{-t}$ : Solving PDE by Fourier Transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I'm pretty new to calculus and I'm trying to solve the following equation:

$u\in C^{2}\left ( \mathbb{R} \times  (0, \infty )  \right ) \cap C\left ( \mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty] \right )$

$u_t = u_{xx} + H_1(x)e^{-t}$

$u(x,0) = 0$

where

$H_b(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}0, ~~if \left | x \right | < b\\0,~~ if \left | x \right | >b  \end{matrix}\right.$

I am trying to solve by applying the Fourier Transform over x variable. The equation is:

$\frac{\partial \hat{u}(w,t) }{\partial t} = -w^2\hat{u}(w,t) + \hat{H_1}(w)e^{-t}~~~~~~~~~~, t>0$

$\hat{u}(w,0) = 0$

Applying the integrating factor $e^{-w^2 t}$, I have:

$\frac{\partial \ }{\partial t}\left (\hat{u}(w,t) e^{-w^2 t} \right ) = -w^2e^{-w^2 t}\hat{u}(w,t) + \hat{H_1}(w)e^{-t}e^{-w^2 t}$

Following:

$-w^2e^{-w^2 t}\hat{u}(w,t) + e^{-w^2 t}\frac{\partial \ }{\partial x}\left (\hat{u}(w,t) \right ) = -w^2e^{-w^2 t}\hat{u}(w,t) + \hat{H_1}(w)e^{-t(w^2+1)}$

Integrating both sides over [0, t], I have:

$\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{t}\frac{\partial \ }{\partial s}\left (e^{-w^2 s}\hat{u}(w,s) \right )ds = \int_{0}^{t}\hat{H_1}(w)e^{-s(w^2+1)}ds$
$\Rightarrow e^{-w^2 t}\hat{u}(w,t) - e^{-w^2 0}\hat{u}(w,0) = \int_{0}^{t}\hat{H_1}(w)e^{-s(w^2+1)}ds$
$\Rightarrow \hat{u}(w,t) = e^{w^2 t}\int_{0}^{t}\hat{H_1}(w)e^{-t(w^2+1)}$

Now, applying the inverse of Fourier:

$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{u}(w,t)e^{-iwx}dw$
$\Rightarrow u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[e^{w^2 t}\int_{0}^{t}\hat{H_1}(w)e^{-t(w^2+1)}]e^{-iwx}dw$

I guess that I can use the linearity of the equation to rearrange it. My questions are:

- Am I right so far?
- What Should I do with the $\hat{H_1}(w)$?

Thanks,

Uirá

Comment: This looks like a non-homogeneous heat equation. In any case it's an infinite dimensional analog of $Ax=b$. The general solution is $x=A^{-1}b+\phi$ where $\phi\in \mathrm{Ker}(A)$. A procedure to compute $A^{-1}b$ is to find the propagator of $A$. Are you familiar with these concepts? You can find a lot of stuff on Wikipedia.

Comment: Not really, but I will search about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have editing your answer directly so that you can compare.*

The equation is:

$\frac{\partial \hat{u}(w,t) }{\partial t} = -w^2\hat{u}(w,t) + \hat{H_1}(w)e^{-t}~~~~~~~~~~, t>0$

$\hat{u}(w,0) = 0$

Applying the integrating factor $e^{w^2 t}$, I have:

$\frac{\partial \ }{\partial t}\left (\hat{u}(w,t) e^{w^2 t} \right ) = \hat{H_1}(w)e^{-t}e^{w^2 t}$

Integrating both sides over $[0, t]$, and using $u(x,0)=0$, I have:

$\hat{u}(w,t)e^{w^{2}t}=\int_{0}^{t}\hat{H_1}(w)e^{-s}e^{w^{2}s}ds$

$\hat{u}(w,t)=\int_{0}^{t}\hat{H_1}(w)e^{-s}e^{-(t-s)w^{2}}ds$

Using the convolution theorem,

$
 \hat{H_1}(w)e^{-(t-s)w^{2}}=\hat{H_1}(w)\hat{G}(w)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\widehat{H_1\star G},\;\;\;
G(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(t-s)}}e^{-x^{2}/4(t-s)}
$

Now, applying the inverse of Fourier:

$u(x,t)=\int_{0}^{t}e^{-s}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi(t-s)}}e^{-(x-y)^{2}/4(t-s)}H_1(y)dyds
$

I could be off by a multiplicative constant. I'm constantly losing constants.

Comment: Hi @TrialAndError, could you show me how do you end up in $\frac{\partial \ }{\partial t}\left (\hat{u}(w,t) e^{w^2 t} \right ) = \hat{H_1}(w)e^{-t}e^{w^2 t}$ after applied the integrating factor? I didn't understand it

Comment: @ucaiado : Differentiate in $t$ and see if you don't get the previous equation: $\frac{\partial \hat{u}(w,t)}{\partial t}e^{w^{2}t}+w^{2}\hat{u}(w,t)e^{w^{2}t}=\hat{H_1}(w)e^{-t}e^{w^{2}t}$. Does that match? If you have $f'+af$, then you multiply by $e^{\int adt}$ and you get $e^{\int adt}f'+ae^{\int adt}f=\frac{d}{dt}(e^{\int a dt}f)$

Comment: ow....now I see. Thank you =)

Comment: @ucaiado : You're welcome.